# Reordering text in DOORS layout column using DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

I have seen this question asked for numbers, but my layout column consists of strings of text.  There is no inherent order to the strings and the possible values for the attribute connected to an object could be, for example "apple", "orange", "banana", or "kiwi".  The column I want looks for in-links from another module and each in-link can have multiple values for the attribute in question.  Ultimately I want the values to be ordered "orange", "banana", "kiwi", "apple" depending on what values each linked objects have.  For example, if the linked object contains all 4 then you would get the list of the full order.  If it only has banana and apple you would return the value for the column "banana" , "kiwi".  Sorry I don't have a code sample.  At this point it would just be the stock layout column DXL though.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If your real world is really as simple as your example, it might be sufficient to just have a combination of if statement s, like (pseudocode)

```
if linked_values contains "orange"
  display "orange\n"
if linked_values contains "banana"
  display "banana\n"
```

and you have a nice, sorted list of values.

If not, you need real sorting.
Sorting in DXL is usually done using skip lists. When you iterate over a skip list, you get the values in the order of the sorted keys (note that keys are unique, there cannot be two objects with the same key in a skip list).
So, it would be your task to create a mapping that for each entry to be stored calculates a key that represents the correct order and a temporary skip list.

If I understand your example correctly, you would have a mapping

- orange: a
- banana: b
- kiwi: c
- apple: d

Let's assume that there may be multiple oranges per object and you want to list all of them, because you do not only want to display the fruit but also some attribute like size or quality. In this case, you would create sort keys like this:

Object 1 has linked objects with the values: first apple (big), second apple (small), kiwi (medium), third apple (big), orange. This would make the following skip list:

- key: d001, value: apple (big)
- key: d002, value: apple (small)
- key: c003, value: kiwi (medium)
- key: d004, value: apple (big)
- key: a005, value: orange

If you want to sort first by fruit, then by size, and you code your sizes by a: big, b: medium, c: small, d: undefined, you would have keys like:

- da001
- dc002
- cb003
- da004
- ad005

Comment: Thank you, that gives me some more insight into how keys work for skip lists.  I am a little hazy on how I code this using the column layout DXL from the wizard though.  Basically right now I have been running the wizard, and creating the skip list and a few variables.

Comment: So as the column DXL runs it's iterating over all of these in-links from another module and dumping the value into a variable "s." s is then assigned then assigned to the disp variable in the stock layout DXL.  The problem comes when I go to create the order for things to be put in the skip list.

Comment: Ultimately I am using put(skip, order,disp)
to fill the skip list, but I don't seem to be able to make order right.  The actual list I am working with is super long so I haven't been able to try this, but would making

String order = {apple (big), apple (small), kiwi (big), kiwi (small), orange (big), etc.} 
work to put items in the skip list properly?